# How to collect metrics for NFS?

Tags: linux-networking, nfs

Our worker nodes in cluster use NFS shares, and I need to create dashboard to display health and quality of NFS shares. Is there any way to get on client some metrics, like response time, throughput, latency etc?

Answer (score -1):

You could try ntop. It has a cmdline and web interface for getting stats.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntop

Or

Nmap has scripts to do stats.
https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/nfs-statfs.html